# What's the cleanest way to get an ODBC decimal to C# int?

Tags: c#, odbc

I working on some code that queries an DB2 database via an ODBC connection. The value represents an employee number, but it is stored in the DB as a decimal. There are several columns like this, so I am looking for the cleanest and safest way to convert the values to ints.

I can try `dr.GetInt32(colIndex)`, but I try to avoid using column ordinals to minimized confusion. I didn't see a method on `dr["MyCol"].GetOrdinal()`.

I can do it in two steps, but I don't want this method to get really long with conversion. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(int)dr.GetDecimal(dr.GetOrdinal("MyCol"))
```

Comment: Can I do dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("MyCol")) or do I need to box it?

Comment: Tested it! I can do GetInt32 with a decimal column and skip the cast. Thanks, dude!

Comment: Keep in mind, different flavors of dbs may react differently to retrieving values by type that doesn't match column definition, in many cases it'll fail. it looks like db2 is pretty lenient in this particular case, but it's a good practice to keep it matched.

Comment: The type of the object in the datareader (for the column in question) is System.Decimal. So, doing a GetInt32 should be more of a .NET type conversion thing than a DB2 thing at my point in the code.